# How to use regex to remove punctuations in a sentence

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to take from a file all the valid words. Valid words are defined as normal characters that can appear like so:

```
don't won't can't
```

and I have to ignore commas periods and exclamation points.

I have gotten the expression to just get characters but now it won't get words like `don't and can't or won't`.

This is the expression I am using `"[^A-Za-z]+"` and I have tried `"\'[^A-Za-z]+"` but this breaks and allows all characters. Does anyone have any idea what I can use to get normal words including don't and won't and can't and such words.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[^A-Za-z]` Would mean anything NOT matching those character ranges! Try this:

```
[A-Za-z']
```

You may need to escape the single quote, in which case you'll probably need to escape the slash that escapes it:

```
[A-Za-z\\']
```

Comment: I am doing [^A-Za-z\']+ is this fine ?

Comment: Remove the `^`, that means don't match anything in the square brackets!

Comment: if I don't than it prints out characters and spaces that is why I added that

Comment: 'Scanner wordScanner = new Scanner(file);  wordScanner.useDelimiter("[^A-Za-z\']+");while (wordScanner.hasNext()) {String word = wordScanner.next(); System.out.println(word)}'

Comment: Well in that case you're not trying to match words, you're trying to split on non-words - you should have specified that in your original question as all your answers are now going to be opposite of what they should be!

Comment: is that good or bad ? sorry I haven't used regex much so I am a noob to them.

Answer (score 0):

Another way (using abbreviations) is: `\b[\w']+`

Comment: But this will allow `0-9` and `_` too which the OP might not want to have as words.

Comment: @mathematical.coffee: Agreed. By the way, to test regex in Java, I wrote a small test program back in 2005 which I still regularly use to build them: http://sourceforge.net/projects/javaregextester/

Answer (score 0):

This will match letters from any language and exclude numbers.

```
\b[\p{L}\!\'\?]+
```

Here is a very good resource for regular expressions.
http://www.regular-expressions.info/